# SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE not working on Android 8

Tags: android, user-interface

We have an app that is used at night.  I would like to dim or minimize the navigation buttons in that mode.

```
public static final int NIGHT_VISION_FLAGS = ( View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE );

View v = getWindow().getDecorView();
v.setSystemUiVisibility( NIGHT_VISION_FLAGS );
```

This works just fine on Android 4, 5, 6 and 7.  On 8 & 9 it seems to have no effect.

In addition I'm calling the following to dim the navigation buttons:

```
Window win = getWindow();
WindowManager.LayoutParams params = win.getAttributes();
params.buttonBrightness = BRIGHTNESS_OVERRIDE_OFF;
```

Does anyone have thoughts as to why this might not be working on Android 8 & 9?  Customers are complaining.